Why does my Roblox Ui text label sometimes randomly say "100.00M" instead for the correct variable?
I generaly new to Roblox scripting and scripting and general. I am trying to make a clicker game so I made a auto clicker option for players to buy. One is a fast version and one is a regular verison. I scripted the fast version but noticed that sometimes, my ui would say 100.00M (Which is what I had for a place holder in my scene) instead of "17" (Which is the amount of clicks I had) I have data storing and it was working just fine before I added the auto clicker. I asked chatgpt and it gave me a script but that made it just a little better. I also asked my Uncle who is a very good programmer and had pretty good experience with Lua but he also couldn't figue it out.
